# How can I stop a while loop with a blank line ending the input?

Tags: java

I have a specific layout for my input and need to go through it all and do some stuff with it. The input should end with a blank line. I have a while loop that goes through the scanner input. I have tried the while loop with hasNextLine and also to check if the next line is equal too an empty string. But the while loop still doesn't exit because it needs another line to finish the previous one. If i have two blank lines it works but I olny want one. Someone know a solution to this?

Loop:

```
Scanner tgb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String line = tgb.nextLine();
    while (!line.equals("")) {
        String[] splitString = line.split(" ");
        String command = splitString[0];

        switch (command) {
            case "def":
                definition(splitString);
                break;
            case "calc":
                calculation(splitString);
                break;
            case "clear":
                clear();
                break;
        }

        String nextLine = tgb.nextLine();
        if (!nextLine.equals("")) {
            line = nextLine;
        } else {
            line = null;
        }
    }
```

Input:

```
def foo 3
calc foo + bar =
def bar 7
def programming 10
calc foo + bar =
def is 4
def fun 8
calc programming - is + fun =
def fun 1
calc programming - is + fun =
clear
```

Comment: Did you thought about the `EOF` character !?

Comment: @Zorglube care to elaborate?

Comment: Texte files finish withe an character named `End Of File` (`EOF`), you juste need to test if the current line you read finish by `EOF`.

Comment: Give a try to `while (line != null)` Your solution gives a NullPointer when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop, you don't need to read one more new line(with String) , you can read, using the existing String line itself and also. Make changes like below in your code, might work for your need,

```
while (!line.equals("")) {
    //  while (!line.isEmpty()) { //You can use this as well condition as well
        String[] splitString = line.split(" ");
        String command = splitString[0];

        switch (command) {
        case "def":
            System.out.println("def"); // Added this for my testing. call your method
            break;
        case "calc":
            System.out.println("cal");// Added this for my testing.call your method
            break;
        case "clear":
            System.out.println("clear");// Added this for my testing.call your method
            break;
        }
        line = tgb.nextLine(); //Make this change
    }
```

Comment: this still doesn't exit the while loop. I still need to press enter one more time after my input for it to exit

Comment: Try with `while (!line.isEmpty()) `.

Comment: do you want the while loop only one time? or multiple times by taking line from the keyboard?

Comment: it doesn't really matter. I paste in the whole input at the same time anyway

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a label.

```
String line = tgb.nextLine();
outer:
while (true) {
    String[] splitString = line.split(" ");
    String command = splitString[0];

    switch (command) {
        case "def":
            definition(splitString);
            break;
        case "calc":
            calculation(splitString);
            break;
        case "clear":
         clear();
            break;
    }

    line = tgb.nextLine();
    if (line.isBlank()) {
      break outer;
    }
}
```

But if this works, then putting in `!line.isBlank()` as a while condition should also work.

Comment: You are reading form the console so you need to explicitly type in a new line or some keyword to check on.   The console assumes infinite input.  If you are reading from a file you can use `hasNextLine()`.

Comment: but shouldn't copying the input with the new line work?

Comment: @IsakHolmström do you want to use the word `clear` to stop processing?

Comment: no I can't change the look of the input unfortunatly

Comment: @IsakHolmström then what is the purpose of the word `clear` at the end of  your input?  Look at my modified answer.  If it doesn't work, it may give you some ideas on using a label with a break.

Comment: the purpose of clear is to clear all "variables" that I create with definition. The input can have clear in the middle of it so i cant use that either

Comment: @IsakHolmström Well, I just offered a different approach (see edit).  If you enter a blank line it will exit.  Otherwise I am unable to solve your problem.  Just remember that all prompts from the `Scanner(System.in)` are waiting for user input.  You can also do a `Ctrl D` or `Ctrl Z` depending on the OS.  Otherwise the scanner has no idea when you are done entering data.

Answer (score 0):

Juste another purpose

```
    public class LineProcessor implements Consumer<String> {

        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            String[] splitString = t.split(" ");
            String command = splitString[0];

            switch (command) {
            case "def":
                definition(splitString);
                break;
            case "calc":
                calculation(splitString);
                break;
            case "clear":
                clear();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

And then

```
    new Scanner(System.in).tokens().forEach(new LineProcessor());
```